# Hiding .env file as OpenShift Secret

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, openshift, redhat

I have a **laravel** project that is hosted in **OpenShift**.

I need to hide my **.env** from public git so I created it as **OpenShift Secret** and try to mount volume to **/var/www/magic/**

However, this will cause the deployment to fail with *CrashLoopBackOff* with Terminal showing

> **DocumentRoot Error: Unable to find /opt/app-root/rh/var/www/magic/public, not found or unreadable.**

However, there is no issue for my **dsa-known-hosts** secret at **/opt/app-root/src/.ssh/**

Is there anyone experience with PHP & OpenShift to help?

Comment: AFAIK, your file mount replaces the entire directory. So, mounting a known hosts file at `~/.ssh/` replaces the entire `.ssh` directory. When you mount your `.env` file at `/var/www/magic/` it replaces the entire directory, including `public`. I would recommend mounting your file somewhere else, if possible.

Comment: I think `subPath` is what you'll need to use: https://dev.to/joshduffney/kubernetes-using-configmap-subpaths-to-mount-files-3a1i

Comment: @WillGordon , Oh I didn't know it will replce the content of the directory. I thought it just add the file. I will test it out, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using Will Gordan's advice, adding `subPath` in the template yaml was the solution. 
It allows me to mount the file as it instead of replacing the directory.